# Pastebin pbwrap has AttributeError: __enter__ with io.open() on python 3.9.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

The pastebin package pbwrap from pypi always worked properly for me before but it doesn't work with python 3.9.5.  It's not able to read the input file and gives the error below.

```py
from pbwrap import Pastebin   # https://pypi.org/project/pbwrap/

api_dev_key = r'your key'
username = r'your login'
password = r'your password'
pb = Pastebin(api_dev_key)
user_id = pb.authenticate(username, password)

### Pasting text to pastebin works as expected.
paste_url = pb.create_paste('this is a test', api_paste_private=1, api_paste_name='test')
print(paste_url)

### Make a simple text file to upload to pastebin
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('This is line #1\n')
    f.write('This is line #2\n')

### When uploading a file to pastebin, an I/O error is returned from io.open() called from pbwrap
paste_url = pb.create_paste_from_file('test.txt', api_paste_private=1, api_paste_name='test')
print(paste_url)

### pbwrap.py", line 180, in create_paste_from_file
###     with io.open(
### AttributeError: __enter__
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug that was introduced in 2020 when the module was upgraded to use utf-8.  I have forked the pbwrap source code and submitted a fix.  The file read needed to be moved outside the context of the with io.open.

Answer (score -1):

you can try by re-installing the package by pip command
it will work for you

Comment: OK, I tried by doing a pip uninstall pbwrap and then a pip install pbwrap:

Successfully uninstalled pbwrap-1.2.2

pip --no-cache-dir install pbwrap

Successfully installed pbwrap-1.2.2

Same result:

pbwrap.py", line 180, in create_paste_from_file
    with io.open(
AttributeError: __enter__

Comment: I'm working in a virtual environment created by python 3 -m venv venv in the project's directory.